# get customer infos on success.phtml

Tags: magento-1.7, checkout, customer

I try to get customer infos on success.phtml. I try it as guest and as logged in user.

First of all I get an order object.

```
$orderId = $this->getOrderId();
$order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load($orderId);
```

Or for debugging on a separate page, with an order ID:

```
$order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load('300000040');
```

Then I try to get the name:

```
echo $order->getCustomerName();
```

that gives me: Gast (guest in englisch). No matter if I am logged in or not.

Then I try to get the email:

```
$billingAdress = $order->getBillingAddress();
echo "!!".print_r($billingAdress, 1); //nothing! empty
$customerEmail = $billingAdress->getEmail(); //Fatal error: Call to a member function getEmail() on a non-object....
```

It seems like the order object is wrong, I can't get the total:

```
echo $order->getGrandTotal(); //empty
```

Magento Version 1.7.0.2

Does anyone see my mistake?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This

```
$order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load('300000040');
```

Should be

```
$order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->loadByIncrementId('300000040');
```

Use `load` only when you have the table primary key.

Comment: One different question: Why I don't see all the attributes with his getter in http://docs.magentocommerce.com/Mage_Sales/Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Address.html or in the abstract class? Like the `$order->getBillingAddress()->getEmail();`

Comment: That's a totally different question. Please ask an other one. And make it clear. Give some examples of what you are trying, the expected result and the actual result.

Comment: Yes it's offtopic but not big enough for a question. Nevermind.